# How to modify Alpha Centauri Alien Crossfire?

Tags: alpha-centauri, alien-crossfire

[This site](http://alphacentauri.us/fac-tool/faq.htm) gives some excellent information about how to modify various text files to tweak the original game.

Is there a similar way to tweak Alien Crossfire?

---

**Update:**
For instance, it says:

```
In the FACTION.TXT file find the #FACTION line  
      (e.g. #GAIANS ) Two lines below that, add TECH,[short name],  
      (e.g. TECH, Ecology, )
```

Curiously, the FACTIONS.TXT contains ***only*** Gaians. There does, however, seems to be one file for each faction, so I edited CYBORG.TXT, changing the following

```
^TECH: {Information Networks, Applied Physics}
```

to

```
^TECH: {Information Networks, Applied Physics, Bio-Engineering, 
        Bio Engineering, BioEng, Eudomania, Planetary Networks}
```

but had none of those when the game started. Any ideas?

Comment: But… the engine is the same, and the configuration files must be of the same structure. Did you try these recommendations? Is there anything that does not work?

Comment: The configuration files do not  seem to have the same names, or layout, which is why I asked,